# replace leading zero in mobile number with 91

Tags: pandas

How to replace leading 0 with 91 in (below dataframe df) 
from columns phone1 to phone7  using pandas dataframe functions

```
#        kac   play_id      phone1     phone2 phone3 phone4     phone5 phone6     phone7
# 0  5004490  20002075  0900031349  090891349
# 1  5003807  00601731                                       088235311
# 2  5003808  00601731                                                         088235311
```

Expected ouput:

```
#        kac   play_id      phone1     phone2 phone3 phone4     phone5 phone6     phone7
# 0  5004490  20002075  91900031349  9190891349
# 1  5003807  00601731                                       9188235311
# 2  5003808  00601731                                                         9188235311
```

Comment: `phone7` is not processed ?

Comment: it should be processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.replace` with `regex=True`

```
df.update(df.filter(like='phone').replace('^0', '91', regex=True))

df

       kac   play_id       phone1      phone2 phone3 phone4      phone5 phone6      phone7
0  5004490  20002075  91900031349  9190891349                                             
1  5003807    601731                                         9188235311                   
2  5003808    601731                                                            9188235311
```

---

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'kac': ['5004490', '5003807', '5003808'],
    'play_id': ['20002075', '601731', '601731'],
    'phone1': ['0900031349', '', ''],
    'phone2': ['090891349', '', ''],
    'phone3': ['', '', ''],
    'phone4': ['', '', ''],
    'phone5': ['', '088235311', ''],
    'phone6': ['', '', ''],
    'phone7': ['', '', '088235311']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `np.where` + `startswith`

```
l=[np.where(df[x].str.startswith('0'),'91'+df[x].str[1:],df[x]).tolist() for x in df.columns[2:]]
df.loc[:,'phone1':]=np.array(l).T
```